# How to move this redundant logic to for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am trying to check if a field value is changed and based on that construct a Json. I am checking 3 fields, but it might get increased in future. How can I do this efficiently for this below logic

```
    public with sharing class BankerCheck {
    public static String jsonPayLoad(Banker__c newBanker, Banker__c oldBanker) {        
        List<Object> jsonData;
        Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> dataObj = new Map<String, Object>();
        jsonData = new List<Object>();        
        //move this field status check into for loop, for checking oldvalue vs newvalue add the each field data to jsonData 
        String bankerHome = fieldStatus(newBanker.bankerHome__c, oldBanker.bankerHome__c);
        if (bankerHome != 'NoDiff'){            
            dataValue = getData(newBanker.bankerHome__c, oldBanker.bankerHome__c, 'Home', bankerHome__c);
            jsonData.add(dataValue);
        }    
}
```

How can I move the fieldstatus method into for loop instead of calling the method each time by passing each field name, let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a field mapping technique, then you can use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) methods to get the values dynamically. Here's a simplified version:

```
public with sharing class BankerCheck {
    static Map<String, String> fieldMap = new Map<String, String> {
        'BankerHome__c' => 'Home',
        'BankerWork__c' => 'Work',
        'BankerCell__c' => 'Cell'
    };

    public static String jsonPayLoad(Banker__c newBanker, Banker__c oldBanker) {        
        List<Object> jsonData = new List<Object>();
        Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> dataObj = new Map<String, Object>();
        for(String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
            String oldValue = (String)oldBanker.get(fieldName);
            String newValue = (String)newBanker.get(fieldName);
            String fieldStatusResult = fieldStatus(newValue, oldValue);
            if(fieldStatusResult != 'NoDiff') {
                jsonData.add(getData(newValue, oldValue, fieldMap.get(fieldName), fieldStatusResult));
            }
        }
        if (jsonData.size() > 0){
            dataObj.put('phones', jsonData);
        }
        mapObj.put('data', dataObj);
        return JSON.Serialize(mapObj);
    }  
    
    //need to pass the field value from for loop and add the type of data
    private static String fieldStatus(String newFieldValue, String oldFieldValue){
        if (newFieldValue != null && newFieldValue != ''){
            return 'Create';
        } else if (newFieldValue != null && newFieldValue != '' && oldFieldValue != null && oldFieldValue != '' && newFieldValue != oldFieldValue){
            return 'Update';
        } else if ((newFieldValue == null || newFieldValue == '') && oldFieldValue != null && oldFieldValue != ''){
            return 'Delete';
        }
        return 'NoDiff';
    }
    
    public static Map<string,object> getData(String newFieldValue, String oldFieldValue, string phoneUsageType, string phoneAction){  
        Map<String, Object> obj = new Map<String, Object>();        
        obj.put('usage', phoneUsageType);
        if (phoneAction == 'Delete'){
            obj.put('number', oldFieldValue); 
        } else {
            obj.put('number', newFieldValue);
        }
        obj.put('deviceType', 'Phone');
        obj.put('action', phoneAction);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Typically, developers that use this type of setup would also make a [Field Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_field_sets.htm&type=5) to allow changing behavior without deploying new code. You can search here on SFSE or elsewhere on the web for examples of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much sfdcFox, worked like a charm! will update the fieldset too, Thanks a ton!!